# NOUN + or otherwise in American English

Tags: american-english

A dictionary says "or otherwise" in the following is a British usage. I'd like to know whether Americans also use it.

> The truth **or otherwise** of this diagnosis would be revealed in the future.

Comment: As an American (NYC area), I wouldn't consider this usage to be unusual or noteworthy.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Comparing [this American usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+truth+or+otherwise+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=28&smoothing=3) and this [British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+truth+or+otherwise+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3) chart, it seems the specific sequence ***the truth or otherwise of*** is about 10 times more common in BrE than it is in AmE. But that needn't imply Americans notice anything "unusual" about the usage (which I'm sure will be perfectly comprehensible to everyone on both sides of the pond).

Comment: "Truth or otherwise" is probably understandable to Americans, but do they really use it and other expressions of the sort, e.g., "wisdom or otherwise of . .. " and "validity or otherwise of . . . "? If they generally don't use it, what's wrong with labeling it "British"?